# Download progress is not display in NSProgress when try download file from GoDaddy server url

Tags: ios, objective-c, download-manager, nsprogress

I want to donwload mp3 file from goDaddy server and display donwload process in NSPorgress. 
That's why I'm using Heikowi/HWIFileDownload this demo to refrence.

Demo is working fine with start, stop,cancel,pause and resume functionality.
But in this demo I can't able to download url from GoDaddy server.

How can I solve this?

I'm using this below url:
**http://starindustries.co/assets/mp3/Exotic.mp3**

Comment: pls update your question with relevant details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution that make your user class you just need to change following code in  **Download.m** find **start** Method

Replace following existing line of code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
```

With:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
[request setValue:@"identity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
```

That's it your issue going to be solve. you getting actual length instead of -1

Comment: Hi Nitin, could you please help to fix this!! 
https://github.com/Heikowi/HWIFileDownload/issues/26